# TActionToolBar and TActionClients[], relative position icons and captions

Tags: delphi

How to change position of the caption in TActionClients. I need to put captions below icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TActionManager` has a property `ActionBars`, where each `ActionBar` is a `TActionBarItem`, which in turn has a property `GlyphLayout`.